# Postman HTTP Snippet

Tags: http, curl, postman

I've seen many times over the internet the HTTP request that follows the following standard:

```
POST /v1/main HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/json
```

Postman delivers that snippet upon export of the request.

I've always wondered how is that useful for making a request using the terminal instead of using cURL.

How can I use this standard to make a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a log from postman similar to curl.

make same request with curl with an extra arg `-v`. it will also show similar log.

you can checkout [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) which also does the same thing as postman but more.